# How to display table row by specific parameter?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have rows of table.

```
<tr class='tr_h' title='fruits'><td>This is fruits row</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='fruits'><td>Apple</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='fruits'><td>Chicken</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='fruits'><td>Beef</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='fruits'><td>Pea</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_h' title='meats'><td>This is meat row</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'><td>Apple</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'><td>Chicken</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'><td>Beef</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'><td>Pea</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_h' title='nuts'><td>This is nuts row</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='nuts'><td>Apple</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='nuts'><td>Chicken</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='nuts'><td>Beef</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='nuts'><td>Pea</td></tr>
```

I tried to display the table row by the title value. My desired table:

```
<tr class='tr_h' title='fruits'><td>This is fruits row</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='fruits'><td>Apple</td></tr> 
<tr class='tr_h' title='meats'><td>This is meat row</td></tr>    
<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'><td>Chicken</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'><td>Beef</td></tr>    
<tr class='tr_h' title='nuts'><td>This is nuts row</td></tr>
<tr class='tr_d' title='nuts'><td>Pea</td></tr>
```

This rows generated by php code and displayed exactly like that. I've tried using jQuery to sort the table. But, it's not working as expected:

```
$('.tr_h').each(function(){
     var id_m = $(this).attr('title')

     $('.tr_d').each(function(){ 
          var id_d = $(this).attr('title');

          if(id_d != id_m){ $(this).css('display','none'); }
          else{ $(this).css('display','block')};
     });
});
```

PS: Do not comment about me using title attribute please :D. Thank you.

Comment: why not change php code instead of adding query?

Comment: I forgot add a dot in the jQuery. But the problem is still unsolved

Comment: @JapanGuy The `<tr>` has the title attribute (`<tr class='tr_d' title='meats'>`). I'd like to select all data using PHP and manage the data using jQuery

Comment: yeah sorry i deleted the comment. Why dont you change the php query instead? it is easier and it would be a proper way to do this

Comment: @JapanGuy It's easier for me to manage the data using jQuery. So, I'd like to select all data using PHP, display it, and manage it using jQuery.

Comment: why do you have beef as fruits etc.?

Comment: I don't see any differences between your original table and your desired table. Can you please explain?

Comment: In a minute I'm seeing your code, I'm pretty sure your jQuery code will resulting only showing Apple, Chicken, Beef and Pea which have "nuts" title .... why you have Chicken, Beef and Pea titled "fruit" and other which are not their category?

Comment: @Kiss me Why do you want to manage the data using jquery? Imagine if you had 10million category rows instead of 4. Would you select the data 10million times instead of 1 ? When you use jquery to sort the data like you are doing here, there is a huge performance issue

Comment: @Kiss me in your case, it may not really matter, but if you are just learning things, this is NOT how you should ever do it

Comment: @MohammadAli the frst table contain all data selected. in the second table i'd like to show the rows which have the same title. so if `tr_h.title != tr_d.title display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain it myself ...

**BUT this jQuery code should WORK ... somehow ... just like you wanted:**

```
var pos=0;
$('.tr_h').each(function(i) {
    var yea = $(this).nextUntil('.tr_h');
    yea.not(yea.slice(pos,pos+1+(i==1))).hide();
    pos+=(i==1);
    pos++;
});
```

Comment: Saya jg org indo XD.

Answer (score 0):

another jQuery I discover:

```
$('.tr_d').each(function(){
   var id_d = $(this).attr('title')
   var id_m = $(this).closest('tbody').find('.tr_h').attr('title');

   if(id_d != id_m){$(this).css('display','none'); }
});
```